# Controller testing - The CacheManager has been shut down. It can no longer be used

Tags: java, playframework, guice

I'm experiencing the error as per title while trying do Controller testing in `Play framework 2.4.6` using `Guice`. It occurs with any `view.render` code in the Controller. `redirect` does not produce this issue.

**Stack:**

```
1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalStateException: The CacheManager has been shut down. It can no longer be used.
  at play.api.cache.EhCacheModule.play$api$cache$EhCacheModule$$bindCache$1(Cache.scala:178):
Binding(interface net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.cache.NamedEhCacheProvider@4c8f1e9)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)
  at play.api.cache.EhCacheModule.play$api$cache$EhCacheModule$$bindCache$1(Cache.scala:179):
Binding(interface play.api.cache.CacheApi qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.cache.NamedCacheApiProvider@38fd7da7)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
  while locating play.api.cache.CacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=play)
  while locating play.api.cache.CacheApi
    for parameter 0 at play.cache.DefaultCacheApi.<init>(DefaultCacheApi.java:20)
  at play.cache.DefaultCacheApi.class(DefaultCacheApi.java:20)
  while locating play.cache.DefaultCacheApi
  while locating play.cache.CacheApi
```

**Below is my setup:**

***Controller:***

```
@Singleton
public class AccountController extends Controller {
  private AccountService accountService;

  @Inject
  public Controller(AccountService a) {
      accountService = a;
  }

  public Result addAccount() {
     boolean success = accountService.addAccount();
     if (success) 
       return ok(CreateAccount.render());//<--THIS TRIGGERS THE ERROR WHEN RUNNING THE TEST
  }
}
```

***Interface:***

```
@ImplementedBy(AccountServiceImpl.class)
public interface AccountService {
   boolean addAccount();
}
```

***Implementation:***

```
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
   @Override
   public boolean addAccount() {
   }
}
```

***Test:***

```
public class TestClass {
@Inject
Application application;

final AccountService accountServiceMock = mock(AccountService.class);

@Before
public void setup() {
    Module testModule = new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            bind(AccountService.class).toInstance(accountServiceMock);
        }
    };

    GuiceApplicationBuilder builder = new GuiceApplicationLoader()
            .builder(new ApplicationLoader.Context(Environment.simple()))
            .overrides(testModule);
    Guice.createInjector(builder.applicationModule()).injectMembers(this);

    Helpers.start(application);
}

@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder()
            .session("userId", "1")
            .uri(controllers.routes.AccountController.addAccount().url());

    running(application, () -> {
        when(accountServiceMock.addAccount().thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(OK, route(request).status());
    });

}
```

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT: I have pinpointed the exact thing causing the issue, though I still don't know why.**

```
RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder()
            .session("userId", "1") // <--- THIS IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM
            .uri(controllers.routes.AccountController.addAccount().url());
```

**To be even more exact:**

```
"userId" // <--- THIS. userIds, or any other I've tried, solved the issue.
```

To reinstate again, as long as `userId` session is set for `RequestBuilder` in the test method along with `view.render` in the Controller, this error happens.

It is regardless of whether I use such session in my html or even in the controller. Anyone knows what is happening here?

Comment: Where do you instanciate your Application? Shouldn't you do something like `application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(classLoader).in(Mode.TEST).build();`?

Comment: @Kris I believe all the setup needed is already in the setup method annotated with ``@Before``.  

Instantiating ``application`` again will result in ``No implementation for play.Application was bound.``

Comment: Maybe you're right. Anyway I start a FakeApplication in my test cases `ClassLoader classLoader = FakeApplication.class.getClassLoader(); application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().in(classLoader).in(Mode.TEST).build(); Helpers.start(application);`. But to my mind it's more trial and error when it comes to writing tests in Play. If it works I stick to it. :)

Comment: @Kris Commented mine and tested your code, along with ``.overrides(testModule)``. Resulted in the same CacheManager error.

Answer (score 0):

Move everything inside the test method to inside the `running` call:

```
running(application, () -> {
    RequestBuilder request = new RequestBuilder()
        .session("userId", "1")
        .uri(controllers.routes.AccountController.addAccount().url());

    when(accountServiceMock.addAccount().thenReturn(true);
    assertEquals(OK, route(request).status());
});
```

The [`running` method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/58a150d/framework/src/play-test/src/main/java/play/test/Helpers.java#L379-L391) stops the application and then you are getting an error in your `assert` when routing a request.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I accidentally copy pasted an older version of my code. I have edited the question - the assertEquals is actually in ``running``. If it weren't, it will result in ``java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`` instead. I have now tried putting ``RequestBuilder`` inside, still results in CacheManager error.